# With Wordpress, can users register on the site and use a single account for all features?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get an idea of what Wordpress can do. I know there are tons of plugins out there, so the functionality of Wordpress is extremely extendable. But basically I just want to know if Wordpress can do what I want it to do before I invest a ton of effort into it.

I want to build a website where visitors can *create an account*. With this **single account**, they should be able to:

- Shop in the store (perhaps [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/)) and view orders/etc.
- Interact in the forums (perhaps [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/)) and view their posts, manage their forum profile, etc.
- Subscribe to some "subscription-only" areas on the site

If this is possible, what's the best way to do it? Are there plugins for each of these things already interact with each other well? I'm open to any and all recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Wordpress can do all of the above with ease . 
It has a quit powerful user-management system with [user levels, roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

All of the functionality you have described above can be done with this system, and most of theplugins you have listed take advantage of that in some way or another. ( for example, [adding custom user roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) )

However, although it is possible to achieve with only plugins , Since roles and capabilities must be fine-tuned - in all likelihood you will have to do some adjustments or custom coding .